# Where can I get the wind data for Nepal?

Tags: data-request, weather, energy

I am planning for a small scale distributed wind farms in whole country and a foreign agency is interested in helping. I want to have wind data to show them and I cannot find this data online. Also, if I have to gather it by my own it would take a lot of time so I am searching for open data if I can get it.

Comment: Assume you've checked ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/ and similar well-known sources?

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate to Wind energy data in India. India and Nepal are two different countries.

Comment: While I'm aware that India and Nepal are two countries, the answers to the India question are also applicable for Nepal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dataset from https://openei.org/ that may answer your question

**[Wind: wind speed and wind power density GIS data at 50m above ground and 5km resolution for Nepal from RisoeDTU](http://en.openei.org/datasets/dataset/wind-wind-speed-and-wind-power-density-gis-data-at-50m-above-ground-and-5km-resolution-for-nepal-fr)**

> (Abstract): These data are results from the KAMM/WASP studies for Nepal.
>
> The KAMM/WAsP methodology uses a set of windclasses to represent wind conditions for the mapped region. A mesoscale simulation for each wind class, using KAMM (Karlsruhe Mesoscale Model), is performed and statistics performed on the model output. The results are a summary of the simulated wind climate, and a wind atlas, a summary of the wind climate standardized to flat, uniform roughness terrain.
>
> (Purpose): The product is intended to be used to estimate the wind resource potential in the country including the the spatial variability. This map covers regions where long term measurements are not available. In a sense this is the point of the mapping exercise, but it also means that verification of results has not been as complete would be ideal. There is some concern that the results may underestimate the resource. However, new measurement data is coming and revisions to the map may be made if necessary as verification is carried out.
>
> The four data files are as follows:
>
> - **AtlasDataNEP05_1_1_uni_z50.5.wrm.u_m.ASC**. This file contains the simulated annual mean wind speed [m/s] at 50 m a.g.l. over the terrain as described in the mesoscale model.
> - **AtlasDataNEP05_1_1_uni_z50.5.wrm.e_m.ASC**. This file contains the simulated annual mean wind power density [W/m^2] at 50 m a.g.l. over the terrain as described in the mesoscale model.
> - **AtlasDataNEP05_1_1_uni_z0.5.wam.u_m.ASC**. This file contains the generalize annual mean wind speed [m/s] at 50 m a.g.l. over the flat terrain and uniform roughness of 0.03 m.
> - **AtlasDataNEP05_1_1_uni_z0.5.wam.e_m.ASC**. This file contains the generalized annual mean wind power density [W/m^2] at 50 m a.g.l. over the flat terrain and uniform roughness of 0.03 m.

---

The format seems to be [ASCII-grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid#ASCII).

License is [CC0 1.0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) (Public Domain Dedication).

Comment: Another resource may be http://en.openei.org/datasets/dataset/solar-and-wind-energy-resource-assessment-in-nepal , but the data seems focused on solar

Answer (score 1):

On Quandl, the datasets related to wind in Nepal include the following:

- Data on wind storms and energy supply including wind: https://www.quandl.com/data/GEOCOMP?keyword=wind%20nepal
- Data on wind electricity net generation and installed capacity: 
  https://www.quandl.com/data/EIA?keyword=wind%20nepal

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]